# Dapper always returning false in case of fetching bit datatype from SQL SERVER 2014 database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I am using Dapper version="2.0.78" for .NETFramework = 4.7.2 based asp.net web api2 application.

Here goes my POCO class :

```
public class TestGroupResult : APIResult
{
    public TestGroupVM TestGroup
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TestGroupVM
{
    public int TestGroupId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string GroupName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsPublished
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CountryVM Country
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public async Task<TestGroupResult> GetDataAsync(RequestDTO value, string locale)
{
    var localeLangId = _commonService.GetLanguageFromLocale(locale).LanguageId;
    var result = new TestGroupVM();
    var cgresult = new TestGroupResult();
    using (var conn = await _dapperService.CreateConnection())
    {
        var data = await conn.QueryAsync<TestGroupVM, CountryVM, TestGroupVM>("stp_FetchData", (cg, c) =>
        {
            cg.Country = c;
            return cg;
        }, splitOn: "Uuid", param: new
        {
        @pI_NCOUNTRYCODE = value.Code, @pI_ILOCALELANGID = localeLangId
        }

        , commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        result = data.FirstOrDefault();
        var countryVM = new CountryVM{Uuid = Convert.ToString(result.Country.Uuid), DisplayName = result.Country.DisplayName, DisplayNameShort = result.Country.DisplayNameShort, Name = Helper.ReplaceChars(result.Country.DisplayName)};
        result.Country = countryVM;
        cgresult.CountryGroup = result;
    }

    return cgresult;
}
```

**stp_FetchData:**

```
SELECT CGC.TestGroupId, CGC.GroupName, C.CountryId AS Uuid, CC.DisplayName,CC.DisplayNameShort,case when C.IsPublished = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded, C.IsPublished As IsPublished 
       FROM [Countries] C join [CountryContents] CC ON CC.CountryId = C.CountryId 
       join [CountryGroupAssociatedCountries] CGAC on C.CountryId = CGAC.CountryId 
       join [CountryGroupContents] CGC on CGC.CountryGroupId = CGAC.CountryGroupId where C.CountryCode=@pI_NCOUNTRYCODE AND CC.LanguageId IN (@pI_ILOCALELANGID)
```

On testing the above stored procedure I see the below result :

```
TestGroupId : 5
GroupName: ABC  
Uuid : 12   
DisplayName : Test
DisplayNameShort = Testing
IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded : 1
IsPublished : 1
```

But the method : GetDataAsync always returns

```
TestGroupId : 5
GroupName: ABC  
Uuid : 12   
DisplayName : Test
DisplayNameShort = Testing
IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded : false
IsPublished : false
```

I am not sure why column type: Bit in SQL Server are not getting mapped to bool datatype in C# in this case.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: Bit should map fine. This is usually caused by a column typo. For example, `IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded` isn't in the SQL. Can you double check the column names and property names match?

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for your response .I have updated the question now.  I revalidated it and found still  IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded is  returned as false which should not be the case. There is also another field IsPublished which is also having the same issue.

Comment: Note that, the way it's written, `IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded` is an `INT` and not a `BIT` (that would require an explicit `CAST`); I don't know how Dapper deserializes that. Double check that `IsPublished` is in fact a `BIT`.

Comment: Good eyes, @Jeroen, although I would *hope* Dapper would handle that. I'll check when I get time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is in the column ordering, the components are the type structure here:

```cs
conn.QueryAsync<TestGroupVM, CountryVM, TestGroupVM>(...)
```

And note the `splitOn: "Uuid"`.

The dapper args are: `<Type1, Type2, ReturnType>`. In the query your columns are, in order:

- `CGC.TestGroupId` (Type1: `TestGroupVM`)
- `CGC.GroupName` (Type1: `TestGroupVM`)
- `C.CountryId AS Uuid` (Type2: `CountryVM` - note: **at this point, we switch to populating the `CountryVM` object**, because that's what `splitOn` said to do)
- `CC.DisplayName` (Type2: `CountryVM`)
- `CC.DisplayNameShort` (Type2: `CountryVM`)
- `case when C.IsPublished = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded` (Type2: `CountryVM` - not a property!)
- `C.IsPublished As IsPublished` (Type2: `CountryVM` - not a property!)

So overall, we're trying to populate properties on `CountryVM` after we've moved on to the second object...and it doesn't have those properties.

To resolve this, what you want to do is to move those 2 columns before the `Uuid` switch, so that it's mapping to the right place, for example:

```sql
SELECT CGC.TestGroupId, CGC.GroupName, case when C.IsPublished = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS IsTestPublishedAndOnboarded, C.IsPublished As IsPublished, C.CountryId AS Uuid, CC.DisplayName,CC.DisplayNameShort
```

...or, move those properties to country if that's where they belong (I'm noting a mismatch vs. your database model here - so consider that option!)

Comment: Thanks @Nick Craver for your response. It is very detailed and much helpful to me. It worked for me now :)